# Cordova - localStorage in iframe gets cleared on application restart

Tags: cordova, web, local-storage, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

The index.html file looks like this currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head style="overflow: hidden; margin:0; padding:0;border:0;">
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
</head>
    <body style="overflow: hidden; margin:0; padding:0; width:100vw; height:100vh;border:0;">
        <iframe src="http://domain.com" style="overflow: hidden; margin:0; padding:0; width:100vw; height:100vh;border:0;"></iframe>
    </body>

    <script type=text/javascript>
        alert(window.localStorage.getItem("aaa"));
        window.localStorage.setItem("aaa", "111")
    </script>
</html>
```

The alert in the script **does get persisted** on application **restart**.

However localStorage the iframe uses, **gets cleared** on application restart making the use of iframe not equal to the psuedo intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app's localStorage won't be shared with a remote domain since localStorage is only domain-specific, so you'll need to use a different technique to pass any shared data. Here are a couple of approaches:

1. Pass the value as a querystring parameter to the iframe URL. You can always append the iframe to the DOM etc. or instead preload the localStorage value first elsewhere if moving to a SPA.
2. Use the more common technique of having your parent page send a `postMessage` to the iframe and adding code to the iframe listen for a `message` event.

Additional details on how to send/recieve a postMessage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage